# How do I solve react spring boot CORS problem?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors

This is my spring boot CORS filter class:

```java
@Component
public class CorsingFilter {
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        // Don't do this in production, use a proper list  of allowed origins
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:3000"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Origin", "Content-Type", "Accept"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

This is my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
    @GetMapping("/cox")
    public String getCox(){
        return "COX";
    }
}
```

This is my react request:

```
let url = "http://localhost:8080/test/cox";
    const agent = new https.Agent({
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    });
    try {
      const res = await axios.get(url, {
        auth: {
          username: 'user',
          password: '123456'
        }
        ,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
          "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": 'HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token',
        },
        httpsAgent: agent
      })
      console.log(res)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
```

[Here's what the browser cors error looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zitZx.png)

[Here's what the request looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSAqJ.png)

Also, the request works when doing it in the browser (accessing localhost:8080 from the browser)

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions

1. React app is created using `create-react-app`
2. Front-end and back-end will be deployed on the same server in production.

Solution

1. Add `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"` in the `package.json` of the React app.
2. Modify the `url` to `/test/cox`.

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Note that other popular React frameworks like Gatsby and Next.js also have a similar setting, the keyword here is "proxy".